# Set Opacity from 0 to 1 when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opacity

I am trying to write a page where it loads several objects in an timed order using JavaScript. I've managed to make objects blink using CSS3, but not quite sure how to combine it with timer in JavaScript.

here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var t;
function blink(){
    $("#blinkfirst").setOpacity(0);
    $("#blinkfirst").setStyle({visibility: 'visible'});
    new Effect.Opacity(
    "#blinkfirst", { 
        from: 0.0, 
        to: 1.0,
        duration: 1.0
     }
 );
}

function appear(){
t=setTimeout('blink()', 8);
}
});
</script>
```

my logic is to write one function to change the opacity of a div from 0.0 to 1.0, so it will show up. and then write another function to call this function after every certain seconds for different objects. for example, make div1 appears first, and 8 seconds later, div2 appears; 8 seconds later, div3 appears...

Comment: What library are you using? Those are not standard jquery functions.

Comment: Looks more like mootools than jQuery

Comment: I am looking for a way to not use any library. The current code has the library from this page: http://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-appear/

Comment: That's not mootools, just javascript mixed with jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a lot of code to fade things in. This would probably simplify things. Add the class "blink" to each element you want to apply, and an additional class of 'load-0', etc to specify order.

```
$('.blink').fadeTo(0,0).each(function(i) {//initial fadeout, then blink loop
    var bk = $(this);//can i get a blink?
    if ($('.load-0').length) { bk = $('.load-'+i); }//load ordering support
    bk.delay(i*2000).animate({opacity: '1'}, 1000);//animate [delay,opacity,duration]
});
```

That will hide them at first, then fade them in 2 seconds apart from each other.

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/nw8kM/

Comment: Thanks! this works! my question is that how would i apply this to multiple divs? for example, now the #blinkfirst div is calling this functions. Shall i put the other ids inside of a class and call these functions? for example, .blink #first, .blink #second, .blink #third...$('.blink')...

Comment: this will go through all divs with a class of "blink", in order of syntax. You could add an attribute or class to define the order, and use i to affect those in the order you want. so adding an additional class of 'load-0', etc. to each. then change the 3rd line to $('.load-'+i).delay(i*8000).animate({opacity: '1'}, 1000);

Comment: thank you! this works well! actually I kept the third line to be $(this).delay...and then put in the html <div class="blink">content 1</div><div class="blink">content 2</div><div class="blink">content 3</div> and it works just like the way I want. Thank you!

Comment: sorry to bother you after many days. I just wanna let you know that your solution for load many objects works beautifully. Here is the problem I encountered and your solution solves the issue. I just wanna say thanks! Take a look at this page in case you're interested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867473/display-animation-every-time-clicks-a-button-using-jquery.

Comment: no worries, I added an answer on it for you that will makes things a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

For the blink effect, you can simply wrap the `element` with `setInterval` function and call `fadeIn/fadeOut` of `jQuery` on it.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.blink').fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);
}, 0);
```

Here is the demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uw8Ub/).

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is the pure `JavaScript` solution.

```
var blink = document.getElementById('blink');

var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(blink.style.display == 'none') {
        blink.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        blink.style.display = 'none';
    }
}, 500);
```

Using `display` CSS property to hide/show the element.

Check out the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uw8Ub/2/).

**UPDATE 2:**

And here is the fixed solution using `jQuery`'s `animate()` function.

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    $blink.stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500, function() {
        $blink.animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 500);
    });

    $blink.text($blink.queue( "fx" ).length);
}, 1000);
```

Check out the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uw8Ub/3/).

Comment: This will grow out of control in a hurry.  You're going to keep queueing animations constantly forever.  See this update to your fiddle with a count of how many animations are in your queue.  http://jsfiddle.net/uw8Ub/1/

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that. So can you give a solution for this? Should I clear the queue explicitly or there's already a nice solution?

Comment: Personally, I would ditch `setInterval` entirely and use a callback on the `fadeOut` to start the next cycle.  Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/uw8Ub/5/

Comment: I've added two solutions. The first one using pure `JavaScript` and the second one using `jQuery`'s `animate()` with the callback.

Comment: @JamesMontagne It's a very elegant solution. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thank you guys! these solutions are very nicely written. It's different than what I want to display tho, but thank you for the help! it will be really helpful for my other projects!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code-

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var t;
function blink(){
    $("#blinkfirst").setStyle({opacity: '0'});
    $("#blinkfirst").setStyle({visibility: 'visible'});
    new Effect.Opacity(
    "#blinkfirst", { 
        from: 0.0, 
        to: 1.0,
        duration: 1.0
     }
 );
}

function appear(){
t=setTimeout('blink()', 8000);
}
});
</script>
```